# can I be hacked with this code?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I purchased a script that has some weird code in it.
I'm a PHP beginner but know a little about things like sanitizing input data.

This is the code:

```
<form action="sendpass.php" method="post" id="sendpassform">
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" name="sendpass" value="Send" />
</form>
?>

...
if($_REQUEST['email'] != ''){
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $k = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'") or die(mysql_error());
  $result= mysql_fetch_array($k);
  ....
}
```

What I'm curious of, is if someone can hack the site using this form, because the email field is just passed directly to SQL with any escaping...

Comment: Is it friday yet? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can a moderator move this question to http://security.stackexchange.com/? Rebecca see this question http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/demonstrating-sql-injection-on-the-following/2343 for an answer.

Comment: Surely a good question for security, but it IS still a good programming question

Comment: No system is hack proof. If you have an internet connection (which, being a server, I would hope you do) you are open to all kinds of attacks no matter how many safeguards you take. Although this one seems trivial to defeat, even if you take real good care of the inputs, you're still open to something (even if no one can think of it for a long time!)

Comment: Did you buy this on April 1st by any chance? Since the SQL is vulnerable to injection attack - the mail is probably vulnerable to injection too.

Answer (score 8):

You should use be doing `$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);`

That should prevent any SQL injection attacks.

To answer your question, it's possible but whether there is any damage or not depends on what you do with the data retrieved from MySQL (not shown)

Comment: the data is then emailed to $email (its a password forgot form)

Comment: Depending on how that works, someone could probably fairly easily get the server to send them all of the details for every user in that database. Which is of course a massive hole in your security!

Comment: Of course there can be damage done. You could delete the whole database for example. Or dump the user table with `$email = "' OR 1 = 1;"`

Comment: @Joe / Femaref Since you can't execute multiple MySQL statements in PHP surely it's not possible to edit the database, and whether any damage is done or not would depend on what happened to the data after it's retrieved

Comment: @Dot The php doc doesn't quite say that you can't **execute** multiple queries, it just says it won't support it. Care to do a test because I'm not sure on this issue.

Comment: @Joe is right. By running timed queries, you can even blindly guess table names if you wanted to.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. This is called SQL injection. Anywhere user supplied values are directly included in a SQL statement, this is a possibility.

Answer (score 7):

Yes quite easily with SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes, though I cannot give you a play by play on how that would happen; I don't have enough info on your database structure to know - and I don't want to know. :)

There are some very easy steps you can take to make the code more secure:

1. `$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($database_connection, $_REQUEST['email')`

   *this escapes any dangerous characters that can adversely affect SQL string*
2. `$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($database_connection, trim($_REQUEST['email'))`

   *in this step we added the trim function which takes out any whites spaces - which are used to launch SQL Injection attacks*

If you want more information on SQL/Programming security i would suggest the following books:

1. Head Firs PHP & MySQL (for beginners - it's really good)
2. Hacking exposed Web Applications 3rd Edition
   good luck
   feel free to ask any questions you might have

Comment: Nice answer, please try using the code formatting in your answer to make it easier for others to read.

Answer (score 2):

That should be listed as a prime example for a possibility of SQL injection. Of course you need to escape the `$email` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The $email variable is escaped when used in the SQL. But the contents of the variable can be the escape characters and other SQL. This could result in someone running arbitrary SQL on the server.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an example out of a sql-injection tutorial. If you have to integrate user input in a database query, you should always consider the following two security measures. Both should be applied if possible, just in case:

1. Use prepared statements (if your database-driver supports this)
2. Perform input validation

You should only use the input if it is plausible. A regular expression to validate an email-address is something like this (taken from ESAPI, the Enterprise Security API):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```