# prevent sql injection by converting string to arrays

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

In my Login forms I hash username and password before I execute the queries

... class ...

```
private $username;
private $password;
protected function Login(){
    $user = hash('sha256', $this->username);
    $pass = hash('sha256', $this->password);
    $this query = "..."
    ...
}
```

and in other kind of forms (like Search forms) I convert the strings to arrays and then I execute the queries, that way the query would look like this:

```
$searchstring = explode(' ', $search);
//.... Some lines of PHP code... and the resulting query is: ...
$this->query = "SELECT... WHERE name LIKE 'DELETE%' OR name LIKE 'FROM%' ";
$this->query.= " OR name LIKE 'USERS%' OR name LIKE 'WHERE%' OR name LIKE '1%'";
```

Is this enough to prevent sql injection? thanks

Comment: Don't use addslashes().  If you use PDO or mysqli use the data binding features.  If you are using the mysql_* functions (which you shouldn't) use mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: Use [mysql function to escape strings](http://ua2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or PDO library (which i personally prefer)

Comment: @sudowned I feel like puking.

Comment: Why hash the username?  I would've thought that would raise the risk of collision?  Also, you should check with [Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/), but the usual recommendation is to add a salt, which you would need to retrieve (basically from the password record) _before_ hashing the password.

Comment: Hashing usernames is at least ridiculous, hash everything and encrypt with random salts so you will never know who is who.

Answer (score 5):

Don't trust in your own abilities to prevent SQL injection! Many better heads than yours have fallen to it.

Use mysqli or PDO and parameterized queries. This has the side benefit of allowing your database to cache query plans too.

Comment: More a comment than an answer IMHO.

Comment: Sometimes you can't say "this is a safe way to do this incredibly unsafe thing you're doing."

Comment: +1 : What is it about geeks that they always try to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Yes I will revert my opnion anyway as these other answers are so really bad.

Comment: The important part here is *parameterized queries* because they are good.

Comment: it is funny as there are a bunch of nerds who do not wait a second to tell they have a superior mind and just say "do not do that," do this because I'm better than you and I do so. Dems, Master, show me where to buy you book, ah sorry, you just want  to get some points by posting sssshhhht. .

Comment: I'm sorry you took it that way. The truth is, properly escaping strings so you can put them in SQL queries is incredibly difficult, so difficult that I don't trust myself to do so regardless of my experience. Now it's true that probably the output of `hash()` is safe to include in a SQL string. Nevertheless, I promise that using parameterized queries is the way to go. For instance, you might Google for "php parameterized queries" or something.

Answer (score 0):

There are some very easy steps you can take to make the code more secure:

```
$query= mysqli_real_escape_string($database_connection, $user)
```

this escapes any dangerous characters that can adversely affect SQL string

```
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($database_connection, trim($user))
```

in this step we added the trim function which takes out any whites spaces - which are used to launch SQL Injection attacks

You can see more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541347/can-i-be-hacked-with-this-code/5541482#5541482)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can convert it to binary:

```
function mssql_escape($data) {
    if(is_numeric($data))
        return $data;
    $unpacked = unpack('H*hex', $data);
    return '0x' . $unpacked['hex'];
}
```

... If in case you are not on `mysql` db.